# How do I perform a between Query on a DB that all ready has multiple joins?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join

I am trying to write a query to check if the custom meta values in a custom post type(properties) when saved equals the meta values in another custom post type(alerts)

I can get this work for normal match fields however I am trying to get it to work for a range for example, if 'bedrooms' in 'properties' is between 'a_bedrooms_min' and 'a_bedrooms_max' in 'alerts'. My Query looks like this so far:

```
//Property Meta Fields
$meta_type = 'flat';
$meta_bedrooms = '2';

//Alert Meta Fields
a_bedrooms_min = 1
a_bedrooms_max = 3

SELECT ID
    FROM wp_posts
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m1
        ON ( wp_posts.ID = m1.post_id )    
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m2
        ON ( wp_posts.ID = m2.post_id )
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m3
        ON ( wp_posts.ID = m3.post_id )
WHERE
     wp_posts.post_type = 'alerts'
     AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
     AND ( m1.meta_key = 'a_property_type' AND m1.meta_value = '$meta_type' )
     AND ( m2.meta_key = 'a_bedrooms_min' AND m2.meta_value >= '$meta_bedrooms' )
     AND ( m3.meta_key = 'a_bedrooms_max' AND m3.meta_value <= '$meta_bedrooms' )
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date
DESC;
```

The last two ANDs obviously will not work with what I am trying to do but how would can get this to work?

Thanks
Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are close.  you have a hybrid old ANSI vs more explicit JOIN.  As you can see in this example, each one of the 3 criteria is joined to the meta table on all 3 parts explicitly.  So, the ID should only appear ONCE per ID as each of the meta SHOULD AT MOST return one record, and the record will only qualify if all 3 meta find the respective match.

```
SELECT 
      ID
   FROM 
      wp_posts

         INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m1
            ON wp_posts.ID = m1.post_id
           AND m1.meta_key = 'a_property_type'
           AND m1.meta_value = '$meta_type'

         INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m2
           on wp_posts.ID = m2.post_id
          AND m2.meta_key = 'a_bedrooms_min' 
          AND m2.meta_value <= '$meta_bedrooms'

         INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m3
           on wp_posts.ID = m3.post_id
          AND m3.meta_key = 'a_bedrooms_max' 
          AND m3.meta_value >= '$meta_bedrooms'

   WHERE
          wp_posts.post_type = 'alerts'
      AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'

   GROUP BY 
      wp_posts.ID

   ORDER BY 
      wp_posts.post_date DESC;
```

I've revised as I believe the <= and >= were actually backwards.  For example, your MINIMUM bedrooms from the meta_value was 1 and max is 3... you are LOOKING for 2 to be qualified.

So, you NEED MIN_BEDROOMS <= 2  and the 2 <= MAX_BEDROOMS
what was originally presented is MIN_BEDROOMS >= 2 (1 is never greater than 2)
and MAX_BEDROOMS <= 2  (2 is never less than 2).

Try again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will use this approach. however this still will not work as the '$meta_bedrooms' will always contain the same value so say in this case 2. For the above to work the second join value would need to be say 1 and the third join value would need to be say 3.

Comment: @Robert, see revision and comments about <= and >=

Comment: Quick question on this, I now have around 10 joins in this statement one of which includes a LIKE. When I perform the query it hangs and takes around 5 seconds to return results. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @Robert, can you show the "LIKE" condition, revise your existing question to include that and what it's intent is.  Also, is there an index or other optimize criteria along with the LIKE?  How many records will this "LIKE" be compared to.  You could also post it as a new question too.

Comment: Thanks for your help again @DRapp, please see my new question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672290/mysql-query-hangs-when-using-like-statement